# Kotlin protected property can not be accessed in other module

Tags: kotlin, module, protected, access-modifiers

Just when I thought I understood it, I got the following issue.

I have a base class in another module (called base here)

It looks like that:

```
open class BaseTest {
    companion object {
        lateinit var baseTest: BaseTest
    }
    protected open var someProperty: String? = "base"
}
```

I want to set that property and made it protected so my extended class in another module could access it.

```
class Extended: BaseTest() {

    fun extendedCall() {
        BaseTest().someProperty = "extended"
        baseTest.someProperty = "extended"
    }
}
```

However, neither the static one, not the direct property is accessable stating the following error:

```
Cannot access 'someProperty': it is protected in 'BaseTest'
```

But shouldn't that be accessable since Extended inherents from BaseTest()? I mean the definition of protected is "Declarations are only visible in its class and in its subclassess" so what have I missed? It even doesn't work in the same module so that's not the cause.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    BaseTest().someProperty = "extended"
```

Here you make a new BaseTest object by calling the constructor `BaseTest()` and you are not allowed to access protected properties of *other* BaseTest objects.

```
    baseTest.someProperty = "extended"
```

the static BaseTest object is also another object and not the Extended object itself.

Being protected merely makes it possible to do

```
    someProperty = "extended"
```

or the equivalent

```
    this.someProperty = "extended"
```

That is, access the property of *this* object.

Comment: Ahh I see, boing. What a beginner's error. Sure, so... only the class itself can change it's own but not for the ones of the same type. :D

Comment: @TobiasReich yes, exactly

Comment: Thanks, yea, I must admit I rarely use protected in Kotlin and forgot about how it was (especially since I remembered there was something different to basic Java0. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.

Comment: But stupid question, is there a way only my extended class would be allowed to set that property? I need to set it but for another class of that type. And all solutions for that would be ugly (e.g. requiring an instance of that class as parameter etc.)

Comment: @TobiasReich I'm afraid it's maybe not an option for you but a possibility would be to mark it `internal` and make sure the base class and the extension are in the same module and the only classes in the module. Otherwise I wouldn't know. It might be worth asking a new question for that here

Comment: Sure, sorry for dragging the topic. And no, same module is not an option sadly. But thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `protected` modifier doesn't work like that in Kotlin.

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/visibility-modifiers.html#packages) says:

> The protected modifier is not available for top-level declarations.

But I agree it's quite confusing as written. It appears the documentation focuses more on the Outter/Inner class relationship via the `this` keyword.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I forgot what was different and "invented" something in my head. Thanks!